# Select specific rows from ListView selected with checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have placed ListView in my page with checkbox on each rows. Now suppose I have 10 records in listview & from 10 I want to check 4 so which ever is checked ité ID should get stored in string with (,) so I can able to update my table. Please tell me how can I do it. Since I am new to vb.net I tried something from tutorial but it's not working..

vb

```
Private Sub assignOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles assignOrder.Click
    For Each item As ListViewDataItem In Me.medicalList.Items
        If item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim checkedChemist As CheckBox = TryCast(item.FindControl("selectChemists"), CheckBox)
            If checkedChemist.Checked Then
                Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio2").ConnectionString
                Using con2 As New MySqlConnection(constr)
                    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Update newMedicinesOrders set `status` = @status, `viewBy` = '" + +"' WHERE OrderID = @orderID")
                        Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", orderid.Text)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Pending")
                            cmd.Connection = con2
                            con2.Open()
                            cmd.ExecuteReader()
                            con2.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="medicalList" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
                                ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table class="pharmaList">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="header-row"></td>
                                            <td class="header-row">ID</td>
                                            <td class="header-row">Name</td>
                                            <td class="header-row">Email</td>
                                            <td class="header-row">Contact Number</td>
                                        </tr>

                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="9">
                                            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="medicalList" PageSize="10">
                                                <Fields>
                                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                                        ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                                                </Fields>
                                            </asp:DataPager>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </LayoutTemplate>

                                <GroupTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </tr>
                                </GroupTemplate>

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="selectChemists" runat="server" /></td>
                                        <td class="content-row"><asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("chemistID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="content-row"><asp:Label ID="chemistName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="content-row"><asp:Label ID="chemistEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="content-row"><asp:Label ID="chemistContact" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <strong>No Medicals Found...</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: where are you getting the error at?

Comment: I am not getting any error hence output as well What I simply need is On checkbox selected items should get in to string with (,) saperated & then that string I will directly put in my sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would loop through your listview by finding all of the checked items. Once you have found your items you could then put them in a list or for each call your SQL. If you looped for each to sql you will be calling the database each time.  In either case try to get the items checked first.

Below will loop through you listview and get all checked items and place them into a String.

```
Dim MyItems as String = ""
For Each item in medicalList.CheckedItems
MsgBox(item.Text)
MyItems += item.Text
Next
```

Comment: Can you tell me on which event I have to put above code. Because it shows error and medicalList.CheckedItems is not captured by Intelisense

Comment: You will want it prior to  Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio2").ConnectionString.

Comment: You should check MYItems to ensure that your items are in the list

Comment: On checkbox label I am getting ID by using Eval. So I just need that ID get insert in string.